# Visual Studio 2017 - System.OutOfMemoryException when running Azure Function with large file size

Tags: visual-studio, azure, exception, out-of-memory, azure-functions

There is Azure Function to handle BlobStorage. However, if it handled file with file size ~180MB in my local Visual Studio, it threw “*System.OutOfMemoryException*”.

Checked that required ~380MB in process of Task Manager. However, is it supporting 1.5GB by default?

Later on, I tried [this method](https://www.koskila.net/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown/) but faced below error:

```
Loaded custom extension 'BotFrameworkConfiguration'
Loaded custom extension 'SendGridConfiguration'
Loaded custom extension 'EventGridExtensionConfig'
A ScriptHost error has occurred
mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\XXX\bin\Debug\net461\bin\YYY.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Stopping Host
```

How to running Azure Function with handling big size of file?

Answer (score 0):

A `System.OutOfMemoryException` doesn't necessarily mean your file is too big. There are numerous possible causes.

For instance: if you're using a `List` for instance; the underlying implementation of `List` is an `Array`. If your memory is extremely fragmented, you might not have enough adjoining space available to allocate a `List` instance despite having enough free memory.

Another possible cause:

> In spite of the name, the most likely cause of a `System.OutOfMemoryException` is not technically due to a lack of memory. Instead, a `System.OutOfMemoryException` can occur when attempting to increase the length of an instance of the `StringBuilder` class, beyond what is specified by its current `MaxCapacity` property.

Taken from [.NET Exception Handling – System.OutOfMemoryException](https://airbrake.io/blog/dotnet-exception-handling/system-outofmemoryexception)

The error message `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.` most of the time indicates you're trying to load a x64 assembly in a x86 program or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Rick answer Follow the steps for changing the bitness and  **if you have no dependency on 32 bit then run it on 64 bit**. It will definitely provide you the relief .

Function App -->> Platform Features-->>Configuration-->>General settings

[image]